# Minimal degrees of finite simple groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, classical-groups

The minimal *projective* degrees (minimal degree of an irreducible representation of a central extension) of the finite classical groups are (famously) given by Tiep and Zalesskii [1]. Is there a convenient reference for the minimal ordinary degrees?

[1] *Pham Huu Tiep; Zalesskii, Alexander E.*, [**Minimal characters of the finite classical groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927879608825690), Commun. Algebra 24, No. 6, 2093-2167 (1996). [ZBL0901.20031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0901.20031).

Comment: "Minimal ordinary degree" = minimal degree of a nontrivial irrep.? This seems related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400864/is-operatornamepsl2-q-the-most-quasirandom-group

Comment: Right: ordinary as opposed to projective. That question is related, but note that projective degrees are often smaller. E.g., the minimal degree of $A_5$ is $3$, but since the universal cover of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ it has a 2-fold cover (the binary icoasahedral group) with a 2-dimensional complex representation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. The linked question is about ordinary representations, which is what you're also asking about, right? Also: is it important that the representation be faithful?

Comment: Uh, yes. OK what I should have said is I'm looking for a more precise answer. E.g., what is the exact minimal degree of $\mathrm{PSp}_{2n}(q)$ etc for all $n$ and $q$.

Comment: Because I'm asking about simple groups, nontrivial representations are automatically faithful.